# ngx-markdown: how do i set filetype manually in [src]=" xxx/xxx.md "?

Tags: angular, markdown

Using ngx-markdown with angular, I find [src]=" xxxx/xxxx " can not render as markdown,
[src]=" xxxx/xxxx.md " is worked. I wonder why and how to fix it?
add:
   tutorial:https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-markdown
   In the website, It said:"When using remote URL ngx-markdown will use the file extension to automatically resolve the code language."
   Is there a method to automatically resolve a file which has no extension?
   such as, < markdown [src] = " 'xxx/xxx' " (filetype)="md">

Answer (score 0):

When you check the source code of ngx-markdown, the default extension detection is implemented like this:

````
  private handleExtension(src: string, markdown: string): string {
    const extension = src
      ? src.split('?')[0].split('.').splice(-1).join()
      : null;
    return extension !== 'md'
      ? '```' + extension + '\n' + markdown + '\n```'
      : markdown;
  }
````

I couldn't understand the motive for this implementation at the first sight. However you can exploit it by adding a hashed md suffix to your src url as I shown below, it works just fine:

```
[src]=" xxxx/xxxx#.md?"
```

Answer (score 0):

md file should be under assets path, such as

```
[src]=" 'assets/xxxx/xxxx.md' "
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).